# Checking if key exists in array

Tags: php, arrays

**EDIT:**

```
if(array_key_exists($errcode, $Errors)){
    $Data['status'] = -1;
    $Data['err'] = array(
        "err_code" => $errcode,
        "err_str" => $Errors[$errcode]
    );
}
```

---

I'm having a harsh time figuring out if a key exists in an array, I've tried using **array_key_exists** method, but no luck! I've also tried **empty($array[$key])** which seems to return the same generic error rather than the specific one.

---

Calling err(null, 3) will output:

```
{
    "status": -1,
    "err": {
        "err_code": null,
        "err_str": "Generic error"
    }
}
```

I've tried using the [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) method which returns a bool but it doesn't seem to work, why is this?

[My site should output error 5: Invalid](https://csgovoid.net/api/v2/joinGame?gameID=333)

---

```
//Errors ENUM
$Errors = array(
    0 => "Cannot parse <GameID>",
    1 => "Invalid steam session",
    2 => "Invalid <GameID>, non-numeric",
    3 => "SQL Connection refused",
    4 => "SQL Query error",
    5 => "invalid <GameID>"
);

function err($status, $errcode){
    if(isset($errcode)){
        if($Errors[$errcode] != null){
            $Data['status'] = -1;
            $Data['err'] = array(
                "err_code" => $errcode,
                "err_str" => $Errors[$errcode]
            );
        } else {
            $Data['status'] = -1;
            $Data['err'] = array(
                "err_code" => null,
                "err_str" => "Generic error"
            );
        } 
    } else {
        $Data['status'] = $status;
        $Data['err'] = array(
            "err_code" => null,
            "err_str" => null
        );
    }
    echo(json_encode($Data, 128 | 32));
}
```

Comment: Show us how did you try using `array_key_exists` function.

Comment: `array_key_exists()` returns a BOOL? Just how doesn't that work? It is *exactly* what it should return.

Comment: The problem is variable scope: `$Errors` is not defined inside the `err()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `err` function doesn't see global $Errors variable. Declare Errors variable as [`global`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions) inside Err function:

```
function err($status, $errcode){
    global $Errors;
    if(isset($errcode)){
        if($Errors[$errcode] != null){
            $Data['status'] = -1;
            $Data['err'] = array(
                "err_code" => $errcode,
                "err_str" => $Errors[$errcode]
            );
        } else {
            $Data['status'] = -1;
            $Data['err'] = array(
                "err_code" => null,
                "err_str" => "Generic error"
            );
        } 
    } else {
        $Data['status'] = $status;
        $Data['err'] = array(
           "err_code" => null,
           "err_str" => null
        );
   }
   echo(json_encode($Data, 128 | 32));
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Code only answers are particularly not acceptable on Stack Overlfow.

Comment: This would work, but I'm wondering why by solution won't.